# How to use Kimono API

Tags: json, api

Goal: Parse JSON API data with jquery so I can display the information on my static (no backend) website in a styled list.

I have created an API using Kimono, and now need to display this information. Any help on just where to get started would be great.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function kimonoCallback(data) {
    // do something with the data
  }

   $.ajax({
     "url":"http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/42ts6px8?apikey=363e7e1d3fffb45d424ad535ebdc233d&callback=kimonoCallback",
     "crossDomain":true,
     "dataType":"jsonp"
   });
</script>
```

Example JSON Data:

```
  {
  "name": "HN",
  "count": 30,
  "frequency": "daily",
  "version": 1,
  "newdata": true,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "lastsuccess": "Wed Mar 19 2014 23:23:40 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "nextrun": "Thu Mar 20 2014 23:23:40 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
  "collection1": [
  {
    "property1": {
      "href": "http://blog.samaltman.com/new-rfs-breakthrough-technologies",
      "text": "New RFS – Breakthrough Technologies"
    },
    "source": "(samaltman.com)"
  },
  {
    "property1": {
      "href": "https://www.unrealengine.com/blog/welcome-to-unreal-engine-4",
      "text": "Welcome to Unreal Engine 4"
    },
    "source": "(unrealengine.com)"
  },
  {
    "property1": {
      "href": "https://www.crypto101.io/",
      "text": "Crypto 101"
    },
    "source": "(crypto101.io)"
  },
  {
    "property1": {
      "href": "http://sivers.org/full",
      "text": "What if you didn't need money or attention?"
    },
    "source": "(sivers.org)"
  }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: So its seem you have already started.  What specific problems are you having that you need help with?

Comment: I'm just learning JS, so I'm trying to understand how to use jquery to parse the JSON I'm receiving from the API. The commented out part is what I need to finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need parse the JSON, when you specify `dataType:'jsonp'` property in `$.ajax()`, jQuery will automatically parse the response from the server and pass the parsed JSON object to your success callback `kimonoCallback(data)`, you need parse the JSON if you remove the `dataType:"jsonp"` from your `$.ajax()` call only (with [JSON.parse()](http://www.json.org/js.html), [jQuery.parseJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)... etc).

```
<script>
    function kimonoCallback(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.results, function( index, collection ) {
            $.each(collection, function( index, object ) {
                console.log(object.source);
                console.log(object.property1.text);
                //console.log(object.anotherproperty);
                //.....
            });
        });
    }
    $.ajax({
        "url":"http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/42ts6px8?apikey=363e7e1d3fffb45d424ad535ebdc233d&callback=kimonoCallback",
        "crossDomain":true,
        "dataType":"jsonp"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've recently been getting 429 (too many request errors). The three functions at thescoop.co are layed out like you detailed in the answer above. Do i need to implement a wait between each of the calls? Here's the code: http://thescoop.co/js/main.js

Comment: Only one call per second is allowed, https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203307120-Understand-rate-limit-for-API-calls-, you should sync your calls.